# How to select one item and array of items from other table in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say I've got two tables:

Table1 (with objects):

```
| object_id                          | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL         | 
| owner_of_object_id                 | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL         |
```

Table2 (with schedule):

```
| object_id                          | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL         | 
| reserved_from_date                 | date          | NO   | PRI | NULL         | 
| reserved_to_date                   | date          | NO   | PRI | NULL         | 
| reserved_to_id                     | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL         |
```

First table defines mine objects, and there are only unique objects, second table defines schedule of the objects. Object can be scheduled on different dates, I mean there can be records with one object_id, but different dates.

I want to select data from these tables in that way:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [object_id] = xxx, [reservations] = array( ALL RESERVATIONS ) ), [1] => next object) etc etc
```

How to query it?

Comment: what are you trying to do? if you're just trying to join them, you can use the JOIN commands (INNER JOIN, etc.)

Comment: I want to get these particular sort of array as php return.

Comment: It's a pity, but you can't get array like that as your response. Best you can get will be:
`Array([0] => Array( [object_id] => xxx, [reserved_from_date] => xxx, [reserved_to_date] => xxx ))`

Comment: But you can map it very easy to the structure you actually need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot select the records how you want. SQL returns a 1 level array, I do not think you can get it to return a multi level one. What you can do is to get the records and process them to get you what you desire.
You should run a command to select everything from the second table (no join necessary) then:

```
$current_id = 0; $counter = 0;
foreach($records as $record) {
    //if this is not the first run and the current id is different then the db id then you should add this to your results array
    if($record->object_id != $current_id && $counter) {
        $results[] = array('object_id' => $current_id, 'reservations' => $_tmp_array);
        $_tmp_array = array();
    }
    $_tmp_array[] = $record;
    $counter++;
}
//final add to the results array
$results[] = array('object_id' => $current_id, 'reservations' => $_tmp_array);
```